# I can not get a post on my second monitor, and my computer is being really slow. Any help!

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, steam, amd-ryzen

I have this annoying problem with two monitors on my ubuntu 22.04, I can not get a video output on my second monitor, and i have the latest Rtx 3060 drivers on my computer and  still no output.

Computer is being really slow while im in steam trying to play games and it is really annoying, and every app i open it takes longer than a few weeks ago. I don't know what the heck has happened put any advise for me

Computer specs Geforce rtx3060, ddr 4 16g,  b550 motherboard, ryzen 7 5700x, psu rog 850w.